# Что из себя представляет конфигурация .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Я знаю что  .htaccess конфигурационный файл сервера .Но подскажите пожалуйста что из себя представляют эти настройки.Заранне спасибо

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 

RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?url=$l [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Если можно погуглилть то вот ссылка https://denisyuk.by/all/htaccess-rewriterule/